# Cannot GET /url error in Node Js Post Handling

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have written this ejs file named `Post_handling.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>POST-Handling Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<h1>Register here!!!</h1>

<form class="" method="POST" action="/Post_handling">
  <label for="">City:</label>
  <input type="text" name="city" value="">

  <label for="">State:</label>
  <input type="text" name="state" value="">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

And I have written this node.js code for handling POST request:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



app.post('/Post_handling', urlencodedParser, function(request, response){
  response.render('Post_handling');
  console.log(request.body);
});

app.listen('3000');
console.log('Hello user! Now you are listening on port 3000 at address 127.0.0.1:3000\nPress ctrl+C to stop.');
```

When I run the node.js code, then I get this error:

> Cannot GET /Post_handling

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen('3000');
```

Are you accessing correct port ? Try to specify full url (with port)

Comment: Yeah, It is port 3000.

Comment: I mean, try to specify it directly in <form class="" method="POST" action="/Post_handling">

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST method in your code, but trying to access it with GET method ? Try this:

```
app.get('/Post_handling', urlencodedParser, function(request, response){
  response.render('Post_handling');
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

Comment: As per the documentation of body-parser in npm website, it is indeed app.post(). Link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser